# How. to find the c.d.f from a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given the following density function for continuous random variable x

f(*x*)=2/3($x^4$+5$x^3$+2$x^2$+3x-2) for x between [2,3]

Determine the c.df and use the c.df to determine p(2.25 < x < 2.5)

So first I realize I can't take the integral between 2 and 3 since the area under the curve would be 1 for a continuous random variable. Therefore I'm going to integrate between my lower limit 2 and my upper limit x.  Would that be a good first step? Then from there I would just take my c.d.f and plug in the lower bounds and upper bounds. Not asking anyone to actually work through the problem just want to understand c.d.f better and how to tackle this sort of problem. Advice would be very helpful.

Comment: seems good, just carry out the plan.

Comment: i don't think you need more derivatives thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that

$$\int_2^3\frac23(x^4+5x^3+2x^2+3x-2) \ne 1$$

Hence, there could be a typo in the question.

After you fix the typo.

suppsoe the pdf is $f(x)$ from $a$ to b.

If $x>b$, then $F(x)=1$.

if $x<a$, then $F(x) = 0$.

If $a<x<b$, then $F(x) = \int_a^x f(x) \, dx$.

After you computed $F(x)$,$$P(2.25<x<2.5)=F(2.5)-F(2.25).$$

Comment: yeah I realized I need a constant so it actually equals 1. One more question, If I want the probability that x is between 2.25 and 2.5 I can find the probability x is less than 2.5 and then subtract the probability that x is less than 2.25

Comment: so to get the probability that x is less than 2.5 I would evaluate the integral of the density function provided from 2 to 2.5?

Comment: After you compute $F$, you can use that function, no more integration is needed.

Comment: Alright so the already integrated function I'm going to substitute those bounds, correct?

Comment: meaning the probability from 2 to 2.5 minus the probability of 2 to 2.25

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you very Much! Your help is greatly appreciated